# Adding QueryDSL to STS

Tags: spring-data, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am trying to follow O'Reilly's Spring Data book (2012) and it states that we can add QueryDSL to STS via http://ilx.github.com/m2e-querydsl/repository/0.0.5/ (which is indicated as the current latest version), but no updates are made to STS and also when pointing to this link, I get a '*404 There isn't a GitHub Page here*'.  I have also tried using the book's used version of 0.0.3 and I face the exact same problem.

Does anyone know if support for P2 QueryDSL has stopped or if it has moved to another location?  I need this QueryDSL to be added to STS, so that I can follow the examples in the book that makes use of QueryDSL.  Any help would be appreciated.  Note: My STS version is 3.4.0.RELEASE.